# Local Link Not Opening from Internet

Tags: jakarta-ee, web

> I have created my first web project in j2ee in my local machine 
>       http://localhost:8080/sprinMvc/jsp/hello_world.jsp
>
> but when i tried to open this link from internet ,from other system its saying ,Not able to conect to the web server.
>   For eg: Suppose my ip is 49.67.10.150, i have replace the localhost with the ip .Still its not working
>   Please Help me !

Comment: You shouldn't use your own computer as a web server.

Comment: Why should'nt i host my link with my own wdb server?

Answer (score 0):

check whether you have any firewall/security software that might be blocking the inbound connection

Comment: Any specific connection i need to check?

Comment: @gaurav: Yes, your IP must be accessible from the internet and you need to open port 8080/TCP on all intermediate firewalls. It really depends on your location and provider how to accomplish this (seems to be CHINANET).

Answer (score 0):

I think you have made a spelling mistake the g in springmvc is missing.
http://localhost:8080/springMvc/jsp/hello_world.jsp

Another thing is to check if u could access the webserver from remote computers.
for this try doing this http://localhost:8080/ and it should come up with its working(if u have apache webserver) or something like that in case of others. Also try to see the error logs of your firewall and web

Comment: :I am not able to access http://localhost:8080/  also ,and how can i see the error logs of my firewall and web.Is there any link how to troubleshoot this procedure

Comment: That means your webserver is not running. Are you running tomcat webserver.